# Rails form, ajax (jquery-ujs), on change some input form update automagically other input (like selects)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

The subject is clear enough.

If I have form like this:

```
<%= form_for(@model, remote: true) do |f| %>

  <%= f.date_select %>

  <%= collection_select ... %>

<% end %>
```

How to update automagically the collection (using controller I think...) without update page?

I need a code in javascript?

Because I'm using Turbolinks 3, I have to use `Turbolinks.visit()` somewhere?

I have to change the action of my form?

If I use `onchange: 'this.form.submit();'` I'm creating a new model, not updating just other inputs...

HOW TO DO?

Comment: Yes, you'd need some javascript. Show us what you have tried so far and how far you've got.

Comment: @Ishettyl, there is some tutorial somewhere?